# Add Image to a table Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a RoR beginner and I can't seem to find a tutorial on the following thing:

I want to add a picture for each of the tv shows in my database and then want to display the image by calling @show.image in my view (show being a tv show).
First, what's the column content ? (I would assume a string, but I'm thinking there might be something more appropriate)
Second, is there a way that I won't need to add URL's manually to the DB ? Like if I could somehow specify that the image name is the same as the tv show's name ?

My questions might be a bit confusing so please let me know if you cant understand what I mean!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a gem called paperclip, it is very good.

[Here is a link to the railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)

The railscast is pretty old, so the paperclip is a plugin, which won't work with rails 3.2 + . 
The below github link will be of better use

Also the gem is open source and you can see this on [github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Comment: thanks again Manjunath, paperclip looks good. However, rake is rejecting my migration file for some reason, is "add_attachment" the issue ?

Comment: I don't think that should be an issue, did you put the paperclip in the gemfile and then follow the steps in the rails cast

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, I'm assuming that you want to store the URL's of the images in the database, and not the images themselves. `string` is a fine column type to use for this.

On the second part - yes, you can generate the image filename from other data if you want to. Probably the best way to do this is in the model, maybe with something like this:

```
def image
  "/images/#{self.name}.png"
end
```

Then in your view, you can just call `@show.image` in the template.